# Need an if statement inside GotFocus event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 application, i have created a grid(named as **Holder**), and i have created a GotFocus event. So i need an if statement that, if the grid is touched by the user, i need a message box to be didplayed. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance for your help!

In my app, i have web browser control, in that if the user **GotFocus** on the browser control, then i want to hide an image. But **Tap** event is not working for the browser control. Need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you should use is the [Tap Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it's meant for user interaction on Windows Phone.

Hook up the event with your grid in XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="Holder" Tap="Holder_Tap">

</Grid>
```

And in your code:

```
private void Holder_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("This message");
}
```

Comment: It works for grid but not on web browser control. I have edited my post, please take a look at it!

Comment: The Web Browser control is a little bit of a different beast. To the best of my knowledge, all gesture events are propagated directly down to that control. You should really ask a new question about that, since you initially asked about a grid.

Comment: Do you have any samples or example links for the above things(for web browser control)???

Answer (score 0):

It's not equal to the GotFocus event, but I think this will fit your needs: use the Tap event, it will be fired when the user taps the grid.

Comment: It works for grid but not on web browser control. I have edited my post, please take a look at it!

Comment: Do you have any samples or example links for the above things(for web browser control)???