# Want an if statement for web browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 app, i have a web browser control(named as **Holder**), in that if the user **GotFocus** on the browser control, then i want to hide an image. But **Tap** event is not working for the browser control. Need an if statement or something else that can help. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need an if statement inside GotFocus event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872291/need-an-if-statement-inside-gotfocus-event)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way: add to you project reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll and use GestureListener class:

```
GestureListener listener = new GestureListener();
listener.Tap += (sender, args) =>
        {
               // some logic here
        };
this.browser.SetValue(GestureService.GestureListenerProperty, listener);
```

Tap event will work.

Comment: There is an Error-A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: you can name this variable like you want or subscribe on event by a different way.

Comment: Can you name this variable on your owm?